# Implement navigation rules with annotations in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I'm just getting started with JSF 2.0, and i'm pretty well aware that it's possible to perform this with xml file. But since J2EE tends to use more and more annotations, maybe i can make use of them.

So my question is :

1. Is it possible ?
2. If yes, how ?

**EDIT :**

What I want to implement is a simple login page. I've a ManagedBean User with a **login** method :

```
@ManagedBean
public class User {
   //fields
   public String login() {
     if ( /*all is good*/)
        return "success"
     else 
        return "failure"
   }
}
```

Now in the login.xhtml file, i have a commandButton that calls the login method on click

```
<h:commandButton action="#{user.login}" value="#{msg.login}"></h:commandButton>
```

The reason why (in my opinion) the implicit navigation rule is restrictive is because : let's say I put the above commandButton into login2.xhtml, it's always **success.xhtml** that will be called on success and **failure.xhtml** otherwise, even though it's not what I want.

Even though this can be easily solved with the **faces-config.xml** file (with navigation-rule tags), I want to use annotations instead (I don't like xml files).

Comment: Implicit navigation is about `return`ing the view name from your action methods or just plain giving them on the likes of a `<h:link outcome>`. No *need* for annotations, those are two separate concepts.

Comment: I already know that. But I think it's a little restrictive since i cannot dispatch the view depending on the bean where the method is called

Comment: Can you give an example in your question, ie post what you like it to look like? Since it is the bean which controls what it's methods return (obviously), of course the dispatched view depends on the bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't see why using annotations would buy you something. I understand that depending on the view, you want to redirect to a different page. Since you want to keep this information in the bean, you can go about it like this:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
    public String login() {
        boolean success = authenticate();
        String callingView = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getViewRoot().getViewId();
        if (success && callingView.contains("login2")) {
            return "success2?faces-redirect=true";

        } else if (success) {
            return "success?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        return "failure?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

Of course you can do away with the `faces-redirect=true`, but I found it good practice to use the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Comment: Thank you. That's clearly what I was looking for : keep this information in the bean. But I didn't thought like that and I believed that some annotations could be used instead.

Comment: @user3173787 You probably *could* cook that up yourself (look for the NavigationHandler class), but it'd be magnitudes more complex for no real gain.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at ocpsoft's excellent [rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) library. In addition to navigation rules it also gives you the ability to define custom URL routing to get pretty URL's in JSF applications.

What you can do with annotations is limited to URL rewriting for the most part, but you can also use a ConfigurationProvider written in Java to define anything you can't handle with annotations.

Comment: Jsf navigation has nothing to do with annotations. The *rewrite* library allows you to have prettier urls or tie specific views with concrete managed beans, but that's not about plain navigation.

Comment: yes, that's not really what I want. But after a look in the JSEE doc, i think you either have to use faces-config.xml or implicit navigation